# stop Bootstrap 4 modal video when closed

Tags: bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, html5-video, bootstrap-modal

I have hacked together the following code which do the following:
Display an image on the page.
When the image is clicked on open a modal containing a playable video.
When the user clicks outside the modal close the modal.
When the modal is closed stop playing the video.
But the video won't stop playing.
Any help? I'm new to coding.

```
                <!--Modal video-->
<img src="img/myimg.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" />

  <div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body p-0">
          <video controls width="100%" preload="auto" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1">
            <source src="vids/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [.pause()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/pause) your video on [hide.bs.modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events) (i.e.: when modal has beedn closed):

```js
$('#videoModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
    this.querySelector('video').pause();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<img src="img/myimg.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" />

<div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body p-0">
                <video controls width="100%" preload="auto" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1">
                    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my way of handling this with any type of content loaded in a modal.

**CLOSE VIDEO (or content) ON CLICK OUTSIDE MODAL - BOOTSTRAP 4**

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is("#YOUR-MODAL-ID")) {
        alert('I just clicked inside the modal');
        //does not pop up on embeded elements
    }
    else {
        --> Basically anything you want to stop playing when clicking outside the modal goes here
        --> be sure to call the right statement for whatever is inside the modal

        like:
        - var oldPlayer = document.getElementById('ID-OF-PLAYER-WRAPPER');
        - videojs(oldPlayer).dispose();
        - $("#wrapper-div-id iframe").attr("src", '');
    }
});
```